# General method to find $f(x)$ in $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

It is known that
$$\int e^x\left(f(x) + f'(x)\right) \,dx=  e^xf(x)$$

which can be verified using Int by parts.

I wanted to know whether there was a general procedure to find the $f(x)$ here, or we are left up to our intuition?

**Edit:**

Consider the following:
$$\int e^x\left(\dfrac{1+nx^{n-1}-x^{2n}}{(1-x^n)\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\right)\,dx$$

Now all we have to do is determine the pair $f+f'$. How do we do it? Is there a general method to approach these type of questions?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Here $f$ is just any differentiable function

Comment: I think what the OP asks is if we want to integrate $e^xg(x)$ for some function $g$, then how to find an $f$ such that $g(x)=f(x)+f'(x)$ to apply the identity.

Comment: @user109899 Exactly! I want to find that $f$ which you mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you can always find such a function... Anyway you just have to solve the DE $f'+f=g$ @user109899 found.

Comment: $g = f \ast (\delta + \delta')$ and with $h(x) = e^{-x} 1_{x > 0}$ you have $h \ast (\delta + \delta') = \delta$ hence $f = f \ast \delta = f \ast (\delta + \delta') \ast h = g \ast h$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward with your observation above. Multiply both sides by $e^x$ to get that

$$e^xg(x) = e^x(f(x) +f'(x)) = (e^xf(x)) '. $$

Integrate both sides and we have

$$\int e^xg(x) \, dx = e^x f(x) $$

and so

$$f(x) = e^{-x} \int e^x g(x). $$

Comment: The use of finding $f$ was to evaluate the integral $int e^xg(x)$!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there was a general technique which, given some function $g$, produced a function $f$ such that $f+f'=g$.

Then, given any arbitrary function $h$, we could apply this technique to the function $e^{-x}h(x)$, giving a function $k$ such that
$$
k(x)+k'(x)=e^{-x}h(x)
$$

But then we would have
$$
e^{x}k(x)+e^xk'(x)=h(x)\\
(e^xk(x))'=h(x)
$$

That is, given any function $h$, we could produce a function whose derivative was $h$. So any such technique could be used to integrate arbitrary functions. Since symbolic integration of arbitrary functions is impossible, no such technique can exist. The best you can hope for is that you get lucky in some specific cases.

Comment: ? $f(x) = \int_0^x e^{t-x} g(t) dt$ isn't a general technique ?

Comment: If your goal is to evaluate an integral, replacing it by another integral isn't a general technique. There's no reason to believe that the new integral will be any more tractable that the old one...

Comment: he didn't ask for a closed form.. come on (you probably misunderstood his question : find $f$ from $g = f' + f$)

Comment: I don't think I'm the one who misunderstood the question. He asked for a general procedure for determining $f$ when $g=f'+f$, for use in evaluating integrals. If your procedure for doing that is evaluating an integral, you're just going around in circles. Note that Cameron's answer is basically the same as your comment, and the OP explicitly said it wasn't what he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no general method ,we have to do some observation and manipulation
$$\int e^x\left(\dfrac{(1-x^n)(1+x^n)+nx^{n-1}}{(1-x^n)\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\right)\,dx$$
$$\int e^x\left(\dfrac{(1+x^n)+nx^{n-1}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}\right)dx$$
$$\int e^x\left(\frac{(1+x^n)}{\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}+\frac{nx^{n-1}}{{(1-x^n)\sqrt{1-x^{2n}}}}\right)dx$$
$$\int e^x\left(f(x) +f'(x)\right)dx$$